# Does AWS optimise region to region connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, latency, region

If we setup 10 ECS instances in 10 different regions and asked them to communicate with each other. What will be the differences to setting up 10 nodes in those exact same regions and performing the same task? Hardware specs will be the same.

In other words, when tests are done on aws region to region, is this a good indicator of what tests in the wild will be like, or does amazon do optimisation tweaks that do not allow you to setup an environment that will be indicative of the real world, without AWS?

One test parameter could be latency for example

Comment: Are you basically asking if inter-region network performance is better on AWS's network backbone vs the public internet?

Comment: Yes. Is this an ignorant question? I would like to know the degree, if it is skewed so much that you could not draw any reasonable conclusions @jarmod

Comment: as far I know aws uses normal internet for inter-region traffic

Comment: It's my impression that AWS uses "normal internet" but it has it's own network and will use this.  Ie, we have geo DNS sending our China traffic to japan.  Japan then forwards to Ireland.  This seems to work better than direct to Ireland

Comment: AWS does not routinely use the public Internet for traffic between regions. *"Does Amazon have a private network? Have you thought of that?" "Yeah, we thought about it..." [shows global map of private, redundant 100G links between regions]* https://youtu.be/uj7Ting6Ckk

Answer (score 0):

If you set up 10 different EC2 instances and access it from outside AWS, the traffic will be routed through the internet. So its fair to say you can simulate the latencies between regional locations.

However, if you use services like AWS CloudFront, the results would be different since from the CloudFront edge location (more edge locations are there than the regions) onwards there is the possibility of routing traffic internally to an AWS origin.